# Easy way to parse "February 03, 2022 at 04:52PM" into Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Apologies, I'm a noob with Javascript and I couldn't see any easy way to parse `February 03, 2022 at 04:52PM` into a `Date` object.

The best I can think of is using Regex to split each part of the string into it's own component and then create a new `Date` object. But I'll need a `switch` statement to parse the month also.

I need to do this in plain JS, no libraries.

Comment: I think the `at` is making trouble here. Not sure if this is following a standard but parsing this with Date outputs an error. So i'd remove the at and try again, also consider using moment.js for this task

Comment: @moeses - Unfortunately I can't change the string. I could regex and remove the `at` though, but that doesn't work with `new Date()`

Comment: found out you don't need to do anything despite setting the formatting :) Hope that helps!

Comment: Your intended approach sounds pretty good. If you need help with it, you should include your code in the question. FYI, I'd use a plain object lookup for months... `{January: 0, February: 1, ...}`

Comment: @Phil - Play object is a good idea, thanks - I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this the hard way. I wish Javascript supported the [C standard date and time specifiers](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) to parse date strings, but I guess this will have to do:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtmgc9vy/3/)

```
function getDateObj(inputStr){

  const monthObj = {
    'Jan':0,
    'Feb':1,
    'Mar':2,
    'Apr':3,
    'May':4,
    'Jun':5,
    'Jul':6,
    'Aug':7,
    'Sep':8,
    'Oct':9,
    'Nov':10,
    'Dec':11,
  };

  const regexMonth = /(...).*/;
  const regexDate = /.*?\ ([0-9]{2}).*/;
  const regexYear = /([0-9]{4})/;
  const regexHour = /([0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2}(AM|PM)/;
  const regexMin = /[0-9]{2}:([0-9]{2})(AM|PM)/;
  const regexAmpm = /[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}((AM|PM))/;
  const month = monthObj[inputStr.match(regexMonth)[1]];
  const date = parseInt(inputStr.match(regexDate)[1]);
  const year = parseInt(inputStr.match(regexYear)[1]);
  const hour = parseInt(inputStr.match(regexHour)[1]);
  const min = parseInt(inputStr.match(regexMin)[1]);
  const ampm = inputStr.match(regexAmpm);

  let realHour = 0;
  if (ampm[1] === 'PM') {
    realHour = parseInt(hour) + 12;
  } else {
    realHour = parseInt(hour);
  }

  const dateObj = new Date(year, month, date, hour, min, 0);
  return dateObj;
}

console.log(getDateObj('February 03, 2022 at 04:52PM').toString());
// "Thu Feb 03 2022 04:52:00 GMT+X (XXX Standard Time)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Well with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) you can parse your string as it is and define the formatting. Head over to the librarys' page and open the dev console to play with it!

basically you do want to do this:

```js
const date = moment('February 03, 2022 at 04:52PM', 'MMMM DD, YYYY at hh:mm A')
```

Comment: [Stop recommending Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Comment: I apologize for this! Didn‘t know about moments current state! To help out OP, i found put days.js is the way to go and luckily it uses the same architecture: https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format